# DacDeployOptions DeployeDatabaseInSingleUserMode seems to have no effect

Tags: c#, dacpac

I am trying to do a deploy using DacFx, and need to place the database in single user mode so that nobody (but the dac update context) can update the database.

```
_deployOptions =  new DacDeployOptions
            {
                BlockOnPossibleDataLoss = false,
                IncludeCompositeObjects = true,
                IncludeTransactionalScripts = true,
                DropConstraintsNotInSource = deployConfig.DropConstraintsNotInSource,
                DropIndexesNotInSource = deployConfig.DropIndexesNotInSource,
                DropDmlTriggersNotInSource = false,
                DeployDatabaseInSingleUserMode = true
            };

DacServices.Deploy(dacpac, _dbName, true, _deployOptions);
```

The deploy process (I have confirmed) does NOT place the database into single user mode; however, if I use

```
 var script = DacServices.GenerateDeployScript(dacpac, _dbName, _deployOptions);
```

The resulting script does have the single user set at beginning, and multi user set at the end.  Is there any reason why executing a Deploy doesn't correctly use the DeployDatabaseInSingleUserMode setting as one would expect?  At the end of the day I just need to make sure no database updates can occur during this update - if there is another way (besides single-user) then I am open to suggestions.

I have also tried generating\executing the script, but I am fearful that the script may become too large (plus there are issues with $(DatabaseName) being used in the script which means I'll have to massage it before actually executing it).

Relation Question: 
[Publish dacpac in single user mode using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31041788/publish-dacpac-in-single-user-mode-using-microsoft-sqlserver-dac-dacservices)

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an easy one - my SSDT (SQL server data tools) needed an update.  After updating to the latest version (11.1.50717.0) the setting started working.